# Working of many Browser tab requesting data from same server

Tags: networking

It is common place for two tabs on a browser to be concurrently connected to the same web server.
how the data meant for one browser tab is never mixed up with that of the other tab.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different requests, one in each tab. The web server listens for the requests, it knows nothing about the tabs in the browser.

Comment: 's will you please elaborate.? and thnxx

Comment: The browser sends an http request, which the web servers listens for and responds. The response is returned to the requesting browser tab. Each tab sends its own http request to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, session layer tracks the session of the different web pages to remote 
Server. The session layer should keep track of multiple file downloads requested by
particular FTP application or web page retrievals from a web server. For example, web 
browser can open multiple web pages. Web browser opens a separate session to the 
web server to download each of the individual files. The session layer keeps track of 
which data packets belong to which files and tracks the movement of the file .While 
using the internet web browser works on the session, presentation and application 
layer. Therefore, Data meant for one browser tab is never mixed up with the other tab.

Comment: No, there really is no such thing as the session layer. It is simply that each tab opens a different socket with a different source port. TCP (transport layer) sends a server response back to the process (tab) that opened the socket.